# Android EditText for password with android:hint

Tags: android, xml, passwords, android-edittext, hint

Just noticed that **android:password has been deprecated**, and we should be using android:inputType. Was experimenting with it by setting in my xml

```
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

Indeed it behaves like

```
android:password="true"
```

for EditText, but it seems that if I use android:inputType, android:hint will not work. The EditText will be blank. There is no such issues when using android:password with android:hint. Am I missing something here about android:inputType?

Comment: `android:password` is deprecated :(

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just stumbled on the answer. `android:inputType="textPassword"` does work with `android:hint`, same as `android:password`. The only difference is when I use `android:gravity="center"`, the hint will not show if I'm using `android:inputType`. Case closed!

Answer (score 90):

Hint is displayed correctly with

```
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

and

```
android:gravity="center"
```

if you set also

```
android:ellipsize="start"
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Quite puzzling why ellipsize is something that can affect the visibility of the hint. I'm not seeing the train of thought behind this to help me understand this. Any suggestion?

Comment: There is none :) It's a platform bug afaik, although it has been there for years.

Answer (score 7):

Here is your answer. We can use both simultaniously. As i used both and they are working fine. The code is as follows:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittext_password_la"
    android:layout_below="@+id/edittext_username_la"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dip"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:hint="@string/string_password" />
```

This will help you.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and found a solution :

**Previous code:**

```
    <EditText 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:inputType ="password" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/password" 
    android:hint="password" 
    android:maxLines="1">
    </EditText>
```

**Solution:**

```
<EditText 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center" 
android:password="true" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/password" 
android:hint="password" 
android:maxLines="1">
</EditText>
```

The previous code does not show the 'hint', but when I changed it to the last one it started showing...

hope this be helpful to someone...

Answer (score 2):

If you set

```
android:inputType="textPassword"
```

this property and if you provide number as password example "1234567" it will take it as "123456/" the seventh character is not taken.
Thats why instead of this approach use

```
android:password="true"
```

property which allows you to enter any type of password without any restriction.

If you want to provide hint use

```
android:hint="hint text goes here"
```

example:

```
android:hint="password"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is your answer:

There are different category for `inputType` so I used for pssword is `textPaswword`

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:id="@+id/passwor"
    android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:hint="********"
    />
```

Answer (score 2):

Hint text not bold, I try to below code.

When I change `inputtype=email`, other edittext is bold. But when I change input type to `password`, hint is normal.

I need hint text to be bold, my code is:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            app:theme="@style/Widget.Design.TextInputLayout"
            >
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/login_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Password"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:inputType="textPassword"
                    android:textColor="@color/White"
                    style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_password"
                    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                    />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

android:hint="Enter your question" or something like this must work. I am using Relative layout with EditText as  
If you want to use password,say android:inputType="textPassword" for hiding characters and "textVisiblePassword" for showing what you enter as password.

Comment: Hi Rashmi, thanks for your answer. I'm wondering if you missed my question. I'm expecting an EditText with android:hint="password" and android:inputType="textPassword" to have the hint 'password' displayed when my Activity first loaded, but behaves like a password field when user starts entering password. However, this particular behavior which is what I observe previously with android:password is no longer the same with android:inputType. That's my issue here. On a side note, what's the use for "textVisiblePassword"? I'm not sure I see the need for this particular usage.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I found that if you put the the android:gravity="center" at the end of your xml line, the hint text shows up fine with the android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"