# Android text input - field name shown in field itself

Tags: android-layout

I am trying to achieve a log-in screen like the following:[image]

Where the field's name is displayed in the field itself. I am using the ADT plugin in Eclipse. I tried setting the `android:text` attribute of the text input, but I don't think this is correct because through the password field, only the dots show (the redacted text), and not the text itself. What is the attribute then. I have looked in [the documentation for the `EditText` widget](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html).

The XML I currently have for the two `EditText` fields are:

```
    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/editText1" android:inputType="textEmailAddress" android:text="@string/username">
    <requestFocus></requestFocus>
</EditText>
<EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/editText2" android:inputType="textPassword" android:text="@string/password" ></EditText>
```

Comment: Would you mind posted the XML you have?

Comment: @harper89, I've edited the question. Please let me know if there's anything else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to set default values for the fields with `android:hint` or `android:sethint` I think its the first.

```
android:hint="Please enter your password"
```

its the first one, thanks to a search on SO. Just for additional info it came up with this.

[SO Question about android:hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387985/android-edittext-for-password-with-androidhint)

Answer (score 0):

Share Java code for when click on Submit Button then Show the Name

```html
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/name_enter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/Name"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect"
        />
```