# How to set hint text as password in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

Hello I am trying to set hint text of `EditText` to password chars but currently when I start to type then chars appear like password chars but hint text appear as simple text form so Is it possible to make hint text of password field to password character instead of simple plain text.

See in the below screenshot it is displaying "Password" in simple text format and I want this should show password chars.

I tried this thread solution [Android EditText for password with android:hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387985/android-edittext-for-password-with-androidhint) but did not work for me

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/sign_up_views_vertical_top_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password_drawable"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:hint="@string/sign_up_password"
    android:ellipsize="start"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColorHint="@android:color/black" />
```

[image]

Comment: try setting the hint via code
http://stackoverflow.com/a/4374101/3518278

Comment: @HemantChandDungriyal Yes I tried that but that is already has deprecated, but it did not work for me

Comment: @ViVekH that is different thing, that answer saying to clear your hint when it gets focus

Comment: so whats the issue? , your hint is showing up but hint is not in gray/faded?

Comment: Just curious. If you want to mask it anyway, why don't you use "********" as hint Text?

Comment: What's the problem with your hint ? you want to show stars or points in place of the string password so just change the text ...

Comment: Are you want to display password character like simple dot instead of text hint ? then just set that character into hint.

Comment: Yes Thank guys, your comments are useful always :)

Comment: @TheReader Your message was hint to me Nice ! thank you :-)

Comment: @Williams Glad to help :) I posted it as answer to, but yours was posted a few seconds before mine :D

Comment: Oh I see but awesome .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Thank guys, your comments are useful always :)

It worked for me by doing simply

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/sign_up_views_vertical_top_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_border"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password_drawable"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:hint="@string/sign_up_password"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColorHint="@android:color/black" />
```

strings.xml

```
<string name="sign_up_password">&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;&#9679;</string>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to mask the hint text, better to change hint text `sign_up_password` to `********` in strings.xml.

That will show password masking text instead of "Password"

And changing hint text doesn't make a difference because user won't be able to read text, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Just your `EditText` hint as `*************` simply and it will show as you want.

```
 android:hint="*************"
```