# textPassword not hiding text android

Tags: android, android-edittext

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:hint="Password"
    />
```

This is the code I have in my xml file, the line android:inputType="textPassword" from my understanding is supposed to make the text entered in the field appear hidden. When run on and android device the text is not hidden.

Comment: textPassword will not hide the text input. It will just mask the text with * or circles

Comment: But I tried your code, it's working fine for me.Try to rebuild your project and try.

Comment: Additional check this question and corresponding answers:- http://stackoverflow.com/q/5387985/1384010
Hope it will help you !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    <EditText 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center" 
android:password="true" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/password" 
android:hint="password" 
android:maxLines="1">
</EditText>
```

Comment: `fill_parent` has been deprecated for ages. Why are you using it?